# Got some wacky numbers doing a Student's t-test

Tags: statistical-significance, variance, t-test, f-test

For context, I am currently enrolled in a Quantitative Analysis course for chemistry at my university. We've been focusing on errors and statistical analysis to determine whether the random error is significant. We performed a lab experiment where each student weighed 15 pennies, so we have a total of about 255 pennies, and we are graphing it and analyzing the data, which shows two Gaussian curves at 2.5 and 3.1. I've understood all of the data so far until the teacher asked us to perform a Student T-test, which we haven't gone over in class. I've tried doing a T-test multiple times using Excel's innate T-Test function, a Student T-test add-on, and even by doing it by hand and I've got wildly different numbers. A Z-test shows the variance within the two means is not significant either. Using the formula of subtracting the means of each curve and dividing them by the square root of the variances over the number of measurements added together gave me a number of 103. This doesn't seem right and I don't know what to do now.

[image: This is the means, standard deviations, variance, and count of each curves, which is what the assignment asked for, as well as the histogram showing the data.]

Comment: For a correct problem statement you'd first need to specify the hypothesis you;re testing, which probably is that the means of the two curves are the same. Now if I understand things correctly, you didn't have these two groups of observations defined and separated *before* collecting the data, rather just collecting the data you found that there are these two groups. Please note that *this invalidates the two-sample t-test* and any two-sample test, as the theory behind the test doesn't allow the groups to be selected based on the very same data on which you run the test.

Comment: (Continuation) Of course one could still compute the test as an exercise (pretending that you knew about the different groups before), but I find it important to stress that in a real research situation *such a thing should never ever be done*! (Note in particular that had there been two different groups of pennies, unknown to you, *with very similar means*, so that you wouldn't see them as different in the data, you wouldn't have been asked to run the test in the first place, meaning that a data dependent way to decide what to test will determine that you get a significant result, (ctd.)

Comment: ..., which therefore is meaningless, as the data wouldn't give you a chance to find insignificance.(I'm of course not saying that there is no difference between these two groups, of course there is, but the test result doesn't add *any* meaningful information to what we immediately know from just looking at the data.)

Comment: You don't, by the way, show your "wacky numbers" and how exactly you arrived at them, which means we can't tell you whether anything is wrong here. One suspicion is that you may have seen p-values like "7.2245e-18" and "1.5991e-23". In that case keep in mind these are essentially 0 and not really different; they just look different because of numerical issues when dealing with super small numbers.

Answer (score 13):

First, it would be good to note that the reason for having two curves like you do is that the weight of the US penny changed in 1982, from 3.11 g to 2.5 g.

Second, two means separated by about 30 sds should yield a very large t, just by intuition. Looked at another way, we know that pennies are made with very little error and that the weight changed dramatically. A huge t is expected.

Next, the formula for a two sample t-test is a bit tricky when the variances are unequal. I would use either an online calculator or SAS or R or Python (I wouldn't use Excel).

You didn't give the raw data, but it looks more-or-less normal and we can simulate:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(149, 2.50, 0.02)
y <- rnorm(106, 3.09, 0.055)

t.test(x,y)  #t = -101.23, p < 2.2 e-16
```

Comment: For @WillAlmy's convenience: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##Vco7CsAgDADQ3VM4KtgQf4VCPUzBjFrQDHp6u7RD3/zaWp0YOlFW1vmgxZDnJlu9W1E12XAYWeiqyUFEI3tOCOi0mL@F@7s84PGtGLUQDEyd1TBTr/UA). Play around with the numbers. F.ex, see how close you can make the means while still having the test find a significant difference.

Comment: +1 And I wish I could upvote again for the obscure trivia. People here have such a variety of interests!

Comment: @mkt  One of the reasons I loved being a freelance statistical consultant is that I got to learn a little bit about a LOT of things. From epilepsy to HIV to the outbreak of civil wars to the organization of sheriff's departments.   That suits me.